# sample void_t example does not compile with intel compiler 19.0.4

Tags: c++, c++17, icc, void-t

I'm trying to compile the cppreference example code of void_t with intel compiler :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
 
class A {};
 
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_iterable : std::false_type {};
template <typename T>
struct is_iterable<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().begin()),
                                  decltype(std::declval<T>().end())>>
    : std::true_type {};
 
// An iterator trait which value_type is always the value_type of the 
// iterated container, even with back_insert_iterator which value_type is void
 
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct iterator_trait 
: std::iterator_traits<T> {};
template <typename T>
struct iterator_trait<T, std::void_t<typename T::container_type>> 
: std::iterator_traits<typename T::container_type::iterator> {};
 
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << is_iterable<std::vector<double>>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << is_iterable<std::map<int, double>>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << is_iterable<double>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << is_iterable<A>::value << '\n';
 
 
    std::vector<int> v;
 
    std::cout << std::is_same<iterator_trait<decltype(std::back_inserter(v))>::value_type
    , iterator_trait<decltype(v.cbegin())>::value_type >::value << '\n';
}
```

I have the following error :

```
main.cpp(11): error: namespace "std" has no member "void_t"
  struct is_iterable<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().begin()),
                             ^

main.cpp(11): error: expected a ">"
  struct is_iterable<T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T>().begin()),
                                   ^

main.cpp(12): error: expected a ";"
                                    decltype(std::declval<T>().end())>>
                                                                     ^

main.cpp(22): error: namespace "std" has no member "void_t"
  struct iterator_trait<T, std::void_t<typename T::container_type>>
                                ^

main.cpp(22): error: expected a ">"
  struct iterator_trait<T, std::void_t<typename T::container_type>>
                                      ^

main.cpp(22): error: expected a ";"
  struct iterator_trait<T, std::void_t<typename T::container_type>>
                                                                 ^

compilation aborted for main.cpp (code 2)
```

I use the following line for compilation :

```
icpc -std=c++17 main.cpp
```

and my icpc version is :

```
icpc --version
icpc (ICC) 19.0.4.243 20190416
Copyright (C) 1985-2019 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

Is that mean that the 2019 version of icpc does not compile void_t ? That seems strange because it works on godbolt : https://godbolt.org/z/xoT8vr

Comment: The error output looks just like when compiling with `-std=c++14` instead of 17 in godbolt. Odd ...

Comment: [cppreference list of compiler support for C++ features](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) It seems that Intel compiler doesn't have full support for C++17 yet, but there's no column for this one in table where `void_t` support is listed. I guess you can try to check directly at source if it's supported or not.

Comment: It may be related to which implementation of the C++ Standard Library is used more than to a compiler version. Does your `icpc` use system-installed libstdc++?

Comment: It may be related to which implementation of the C++ Standard Library is used more than to a compiler version. Does your `icpc` use system-installed libstdc++? Godbolt [seems to be using libstdc++ version 9](https://godbolt.org/z/EEzxjY) while your system may use some older version. [The support for `void_t` was added in 6.1.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017).

Comment: @DanielLangr your right. It seems my gcc version is too old for what I want to do. I have updated to gcc 7.5 and that works. I thought that icpc has his own implementation but apparently, it uses gcc. Thank you

Comment: @Kafka Glad it worked. Just my previous Godbolt link was wrong, `icpc` on Godbolt uses libstdc++ version 8 (not 9). It seems that Intel C++ compiler comes with its own libstdc++ version there. However, on your system, it likely uses the default one. Note that I transformed my comment into an answer such that your question could be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not related to a compiler but to the implementation of the C++ Standard Library it works with. For instance, on Linux systems, Intel `icpc` typically uses system-installed libstdc++. Note that the [support for `std::void_t` was added into libstdc++ in version 6.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2017).

While [`icpc` on Godbold uses libstdc++ version 8](https://godbolt.org/z/df7ozM), your system likely have some older version installed without the support for `std::void_t`.